# Where are Git Stashes stored?

Tags: git, git-stash

I have been using PhpStorm and recently stashed a load of my changes. At some point after that, my PC profile became corrupt and had to be rebuilt.

Now that I have a new PC profile, PhpStorm is not showing my stashed changes.

Is there any way I can get them back?

Comment: Have you looked into the documentation? Stash is locally saved in `refs/stash`. Have you ever seen someone else' stash on your computer? I guess not. Have you ever tried pushing a stash? It's not possible. When your local repository clone is gone, your stashes are gone.

Answer (score 28):

From the docs, the latest one is stored in `./.git/refs/stash` while older ones are in the `reflog` of that `ref`.

As an aside, I've found it's a bad practice to maintain a regular use of git stash.  Generally, prefer many small commits on a feature branch.  This way you rarely have to stash and when you do it's very little stored as such.  I generally stash only when I need to touch something away for a few minutes, and then apply when I'm done looking at something.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash

Answer (score 17):

The actual data stashed by "`git stash`" (i.e. the current version of the working tree and the contents of `.git/index`) is stored as two commit trees.

One commit tree contains a snapshot of the current state of the working tree. There are some tricky bits here, see below.

The other commit tree, I've been told, is used to store a snapshot of the contents of `.git/index` at the time of the stash.  I haven't looked into this deeply enough (yet) to understand how the one is translated into the other.

`.git/refs/stash` contains the hash value for the commit tree that the stash created.

`.git/logs/refs/stash` contains a reflog-like chunk of metadata about the stashes before the one in `.git/refs/stash`.

`.git/index` holds a list of entries for each file in the working tree. Those entries contain the full path and filename and also cached metadata about the file, both filesystem metadata and git-related metadata.

"`git add`" both adds a copy of a file to the object store, and sets the staging flag for that file in .git/index.

For "`git stash`" to create a commit tree, files that have been changed (edited) but not yet staged with "`git add`" have to be added to the object store.  "`git stash`" does this by building a temporary index file.

Comment: I don't have a `.git/refs/stash` file on my Mac running Git 2.22, but I do have them all listed in `.git/logs/refs/stash`.

Comment: @Tamlyn A non-existing `.git/refs/stash` means that you currently have nothing on the stash:  `git stash list` would not show anything for you. The fact that its reflog exists shows that you once stashed something, but you must have dropped or popped it.

Answer (score 6):

All are stored in `.git/refs/stash`. `git stash` saves stashes indefinitely, and all of them are listed by `git stash list`.

Please note that dropping or clearing the stash will remove it from the stash list, but you might still have unpruned nodes with the right data lying around.